# An analysis problem on Hilbert space

Tags: real-analysis

Are $l^p$ and $L^{p}$ space Hilbert spaces?Except for $p=2$,I can not find a standard inner product on them.

My opinion:$l^p$ and $L^p$ spaces are Hilbert space iff $p=2$(Not sure,an intuition without a reliable proof).

Comment: Read about [the parallelogram law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram_law).

Comment: Thank you for pointing out straightly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Banachspace $(X,\|\cdot\|)$ is a Hilbertspace if and only if the norm satisfies the [parallelogram law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram_law).

The accepted example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/621934/l10-1-is-not-a-hilbert-space?rq=1) proves for $1\leq p\leq\infty$ that $L^p([0,1])$ is a Hilbertspace if and only if $p=2$.

Comment: My opinion comes from  user Daniel Schepler...So is he right?

Comment: I don't know Daniel Schepler, but from the link you can see, that if the space is a Hilbertspace, then we get $\langle u,v\rangle=\frac14(\|u+v\|^2-\|u-v\|^2)$ which is bilinear if and only if $p=2$.