# Is every Hilbert space separable?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, inner-products

A Hilbert space is a complete inner product space; that is any Cauchy sequence is convergent using the metric induced by the inner product.

From Wikipedia: A Hilbert space is separable if and only if it has a countable orthonormal basis.

What are the examples of non-separable Hilbert spaces?
From an applied point of view, are all interesting (finite or infinite) Hilbert spaces separable?

Comment: An example of a non-separable Hilbert space is $L^2$, the space of square integrable functions. This space is widely applicable in quantum mechanics and probability theory.

Comment: @Alex $L^2$ is separable since $L^2([0,1])$ is separable, see also the Hermite functions. Now it is not a RKHS

Comment: @reuns separability of $L^2(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mu)$ depends on the choice of measure space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mu)$. $L^2([0,1])$ (with the lebesgue measure and borel $\sigma$-algebra) is separable but that has nothing to do with separability of other $L^2$-spaces.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I appreciate your help. So can we say at least all RKHS are separable?

Comment: @nobody You take a non-locally finite measure to obtain non-separability ?

Comment: @reuns iirc local finiteness is a topological property so might not even make sense for some measure spaces. An easy example of a nonseparable $L^2$ space is $L^2([0,1], P([0,1]), \mu)$ where $\mu$ is the counting measure. The indicator functions of points are pairwise distance $\sqrt{2}$ apart and since there are uncountably many such functions the space isn't separable by a standard argument. Of course this example isn't locally finite w.r.t. the usual topology.

Comment: @nobody Yes but I don't think you should call it an $L^2$ space then.

Comment: @reuns You're free to call whatever you want an $L^2$ space. Unfortunately here you disagree with common usage since $([0,1], P([0,1]), \mu)$ is a measure space against which we have a notion of the Lebesgue integral.

Comment: @nobody Locally finite means Integrating locally constant functions makes sense. Otherwise it becomes very different  so at the very least you should mention that it is.

Comment: @reuns What is your definition of locally constant that avoids using a topology?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The set of almost periodic functions with the inner product $$\langle f, g \rangle = \lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{1}{2N} \int_{-N}^N f(x) \overline{g(x)}dx$$ has an uncountable orthonormal family $\{e^{i \omega x}\}_{\omega \in \mathbb{R}}$. Its completion is a non-separable Hilbert space.

Answer (score 26):

The space $l^2(\mathbb R)$ is another example of a non-separable Hilbert space: It consists of all functions $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ such that $f(x)\ne0$ only for countable many $x$, and
$$
\sum_{x\in \mathbb R}f(x)^2 <\infty.
$$
It is easy to see that this is a Hilbert space, the crucial argument is that the countable union of countable sets is countable.

The functions $f_y$ defined by
$$
f_y(x) = \begin{cases} 1 &\text{ if } x=y\\ 0 & \text{ else}\end{cases}
$$
are an uncountable set of elements with distance $\sqrt2$, hence $l^2(\mathbb R)$ is not separable.

Comment: Instead of $l^2(\mathbb R)$ I would say $l^2(S)$ where $S$ is an arbitrary uncountable set. Also, the functions $f_y$ form a base which means the dimension of a Hilbert space can be any cardinal number.

Comment: What I wonder, though, is: has there been any research on non-separable / uncountably-dimensional Hilbert spaces? In particular, we know that for any countable cardinal number $k$ (so finite ones and $\aleph_0$) there is (up to isomorphism) exactly one $k$-dimensional Hilbert space. Is it so for uncountable cardinals, too? The $l^2(S)$ (where $S$ is some set of cardinality $k$) contruction only tells there is at least one $k$-dimensional Hilbert space.

Comment: @daw: I'm not sure I get your argument for why $l^2(\mathbb R)$ is not separable.True that countable union of countable sets is countable but $\mathbb R$ is uncountable but separable ( by being 2nd countable).

Comment: Separability of $\mathbb R$ does not matter here/does not help. The uncountability of $\mathbb R$  is the property that gives non-separability of $l^2(\mathbb R)$.

Comment: In particular this is an example of a non-separable reproducing kernel Hilbert space.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, some researchers have worked on Fredholm theory using non separable Hilbert spaces. For instance you may go through *Approximation by semi-Fredholm and semi-alpha-Fredholm Operators in Hilbert spaces of arbitrary dimension* by Laura Burlando in *Acta Sci.Math(Szeged) 65(1999)*.