# How $\{e^{i \omega x}\}_{\omega \in \mathbb{R}}$ is derived from $\langle f, g \rangle $?

Tags: functional-analysis

Counter example  of separable  Hilbert space

I got  the answer  here  https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2448235/557719

But Im not able to understand   the given link answer in my mind . My  doubt is  that How     $\{e^{i \omega x}\}_{\omega \in \mathbb{R}}$ is derived from $\langle f, g \rangle $ ?

Comment: What do you mean by "derived from $\langle f, g \rangle$"?

Comment: i  mean how it come  from $ <f,g>$@littleO

Comment: But what do you mean by "come from $\langle f, g \rangle$? The set $\{ e^{i \omega x }\}_{\omega \in \mathbb R }$ is just a set. It does not "come from" $\langle f, g \rangle$.

Comment: i mean what is $f$  and what is  $g$ here ? actually im getting lot of confuse

Comment: $f$ and $g$ are just dummy variables in the definition of the inner product 
$$\langle f, g \rangle = \lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{1}{2N} \int_{-N}^N f(x) \overline{g(x)}dx.$$
Do you know what an inner product is?

Comment: yes i know  but here $Lim_{ N \rightarrow \infty}$ is  given  so i was  confused@md2perpe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $N>0$ and reals $\omega\ne\omega^\prime$,$$\frac{1}{2N}\int_{-N}^N\exp i(\omega-\omega^\prime)x dx=\left[\frac{\exp i(\omega-\omega^\prime)x}{2Ni(\omega-\omega^\prime)}\right]_{-N}^N=\operatorname{sinc}[(\omega-\omega^\prime)N].$$If we define $\operatorname{sinc}y:=\frac{\sin y}{y}$ to be continuous at $0$ so $\operatorname{sinc}0=1$, the above result also holds when $\omega=\omega^\prime$. So$$\langle\exp i\omega x,\,\exp i\omega^\prime x\rangle=\left\{ \begin{array}{rl}
1 & \omega=\omega^{\prime}\\
0 & \omega\ne\omega^{\prime}
\end{array}\right.=\delta_{\omega\omega^{\prime}}.$$

Comment: thanks u @J.G  How $f(x) \overline{g(x)}dx  = \exp i(\omega-\omega^\prime)x$? can u elaborate  more

Comment: My thinking is that $f(x) \overline{g(x)}dx  = \exp i(\omega+ \omega^\prime)x$

Comment: @Messififa $\overline{\exp i\omega^\prime x}=\exp -i\omega^\prime x$.

Comment: ohhh ya  got it now @J. G  thanks u