# Folland's real analysis, proposition 5.30

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

In Folland's proof of proposition 5.30, I have difficulty in understanding the highlighted part:

> **5.30 Proposition.** Let $\{u_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha\in A}$ be an orthonormal basis for $\mathcal{H}$. Then the correspondence $x\mapsto \hat{x}$ defined by $\hat{x}(\alpha)=\langle 
> x,u_{\alpha} \rangle$ is a uniary map from $\mathcal{H}$ to $l^2(A)$.

[image]

Specifically, by Pythagorean theorem I can obtain $\| \sum_1^n f(\alpha)u_{\alpha} \|^2 = \sum_1^n \|f(\alpha)u_{\alpha}\|^2$, but why does it imply the partial sums of the series is Cauchy?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't have Folland, but is $A$ assumed countable? For a non separable example, see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2448229/27978

Answer (score 0):

You have that $\Vert u_\alpha\Vert=1$ for all $\alpha\in A$. Therefore the right hand side is simply the partial sum $\sum_{j=1}^n \vert f(\alpha_j)\vert$ of the series $\sum_{\alpha\in A} \vert f(\alpha)\vert^2$.