# Define an inner product in the normed linear space

Tags: normed-spaces, inner-products

Is it possible to define an inner product $(\cdot,\cdot)$ in the normed linear space $(L^1(R),\|\cdot\|_{L^1})$ such that $(u,u)=\|u\|_{L^1}^2$?

I don't really understand what it is asking for.
I think that it is possible but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you may know, the [Lebesgue space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space) $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ with the usual norm is a [Banach space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_space). You may even now the definition of [Hilbert space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space). The question means precisely: is there some inner product giving the $L^1$-norm? Is it possible to endow $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ with an Hilbert space structure whose norm is the $L^1$-norm? The answer is no: $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ is the only Hilbert space among $L^p$ spaces.

We want to find a pair of functions $f,g\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ violating the Parallelogram Law:
$$
\|f+g\|^2_1+\|f-g\|^2_1=2\|f\|^2_1+2\|g\|^2_1,
$$ 
where $\|\,\cdot\,\|_1$ denotes the $L^1$-norm.
Consider the real intervals $I=[0,{1\over 2}]$ and $J=[{1\over 2},1]$, choose $f=\mathbb{1}_I$ and $g=\mathbb{1}_J$. Then we have: 
$$
\int |f|\,\mathrm{d}x=\int_0^{{1\over 2}}\mathrm{d}x={1\over 2},
$$
so that $\|f\|_1^2=\left(\int |f|\,\mathrm{d}x\right)^2={1\over 4}$; similarly, $\|g\|_1^2={1\over 4}$.
On the other hand,
$$
\int |f+g|\,\mathrm{d}x=\int_0^1\mathrm{d}x=1,
$$
while 
$$
\int |f-g|\,\mathrm{d}x=\int_0^{{1\over 2}}|f-g|\,\mathrm{d}x+\int_{{1\over 2}}^1|f-g|\,\mathrm{d}x
$$
$$
=\int_0^{{1\over 2}}|f|\,\mathrm{d}x+\int_{{1\over 2}}^1|-g|\,\mathrm{d}x=\int_0^{{1\over 2}}|f|\,\mathrm{d}x+\int_{{1\over 2}}^1|g|\,\mathrm{d}x={1\over 2}+{1\over 2},
$$
therefore $\|f+g\|_1^2+\|f-g\|_1^2=1+1=2$, while $2\|f\|_1^2+2\|g\|_1^2=2{1\over 4}+2{1\over 4}=1$.

Comment: For the case of $L^1([0,1])$, you can see this discussion: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/621934/l10-1-is-not-a-hilbert-space.

Comment: Is it possible that you can give me more details? I checked the case for $L^1([0,1])$, but I'm still confused about it. I also tried to use the parallelogram equality, but I'm still struggling with it:(

Comment: Notice that $\mathbb{1}_{[0,{1\over 2}]}$ and $\mathbb{1}_{[{1\over 2},1]}$ are integrable over $\mathbb{R}$. I tried to add details to the answer. Please, let me know if it is more clear now (or if you find some mistake!).

Comment: Thank you! I was confused by the domain R. I thought that the function has to be defined on R.

Comment: Yeah, well: both $\mathbb{1}_{[0,{1\over 2}]}$ and $\mathbb{1}_{[{1\over 2},1]}$ can be defined on the whole $\mathbb{R}$. Or on the smaller space $[0,1]$. The point is that both our functions are null ouside of a compact set!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try to use (and prove) that 
a normed linear space is an inner product space iff the norm ||.|| satisfies 
the parallelogram equality

$$||f + g||^2 + ||f-g||^2 = 2 ( ||f||^2 + ||g||^2 )$$